# Dynamically convert String Dictionary into Strong Typed Class Using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have been searching for a couple of days, and have not found the answer yet. The case is, I want to fill class properties from formatted string.

example :

```
Class Name : Country
Property Name : CountryCode ,CountryName
Value : 'MAL' , 'Malaysia'
```

the string : `CountryCode=INA&CountryName=Malaysia`

What I want is the type of class to be dynamically evaluated. So I use Automapper, and this is my code :

```
public class ConvertToType<T>
{
    public T FillClass(string expression)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> varlist = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string[] _arrayOfExpression = expression.Split('&');
        foreach (string item in _arrayOfExpression)
        {
            string _prop = item.Split('=')[0];
            string _val = item.Split('=')[1];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_val))
                varlist.Add(_prop, _val);
        }
        var user = Mapper.Map<Dictionary<string, string>, T>(varlist);
        return user;
    }
}

Country data = new Country();
ConvertToType<Country> _countryConverter = new ConvertToType<Country>();
data = _countryConverter.FillClass(model);
```

With that code, I got error :

`Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping`

Is there any other way, or what should my code be?

Many thanks for the solution

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using MVC's built-in model binding to bind your query string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dictionary <string,string> map to an object using Automapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper)

Comment: Sory bro. it was my dumb fault. i have not add JavaScriptSerializer. btw, i just need to look out another way.
thanks anyway

Comment: @dskh : I'm a noob in MVC. could you give me some clue? Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Essentially, if you pass an object as a parameter to your controller action, MVC will try to bind parameters to it automatically.