# Library for build objects from key/value pairs

Tags: c#

After writing another boilerplate builder for a class from `IDictionary<string, string>` I'm looking for some library that does it in declarative style.  Here is an example of what I want.  Could you suggest any libs that allow to do this?

```
class Person
{
    string Name;
    int Age;
}

class PersonBuilder
{
    public Person Build(IDictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        // MagicBuilder is what I'm looking for
        var magicBuilder = new MagicBuilder<Person>();
        // MagicBuilder.AddRequiredField<Type>(key, field)
        magicBuilder.AddRequiredField<string>("name", p => p.Name);
        // MagicBuilder.AddOptionalField<Type>(key, field, defaultValue)
        magicBuilder.AddOptionalField<int>("age", p => p.Age, 0);
        return magicBuilder.Build(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might not be _entirely_ a duplicate question, but you might find some helpful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper

Comment: @David This is pretty similar question except I'm not hung-up on AutoMapper.