# How can I map constants and class property values to a Dictionary<int, object>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, mapping, automapper

I have an class called `Contact` and another class called `ContactKeys` that contain `Int32` constants. Each constant maps to a property of the `Contact` class and has an identical name.

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static class ContactKeys
{
    public const int Name = 5284;
    public const int Age = 9637;
}
```

Using Automapper, I need to create a `Dictionary<int, object>` object where the key is a constant from `ContactKey`, and the value is provided by the property of the same name from the `Contact` class.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper) I can see that could potentially serialize the `Contact` class to JSON and then map it. But I don't know how to then get the constants mapped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know AutoMapper and why you need to use it to solve this problem but here is a solution using reflection:

```
Contact myContact = ...;

typeof(ContactKeys)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .ToDictionary(f => (int)f.GetValue(null),
                  f => typeof(Contact).GetProperty(f.Name).GetValue(myContact));
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I need to use AutoMapper because that's what the rest of the project is using for all its mapping. So I don't want to be introducing any unnecessary reflection if I don't have to. But I *will* take a look at this, thanks.