# Simple map not working in my automapper configuration

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to do a simple mapping using this mapping method:

```
 CreateMap<MgalaxyGroup, MgalaxyGroupDto>()
      .ForMember(d => d.Differentiator, opt => opt.MapFrom(MgalaxyGroup.Differentiator));
```

The solution compiles with no errors, but this line is throwing this `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception during runtime:

```
 Message    "Cannot find member primaryStars of type 
 Astro.Research.MgalaxyGroup.
 Parameter name: name"  string
```

But I am defining the string `Differentiator` right here in the MgalaxyGroup class:

```
public sealed class MgalaxyGroup
{
     ....
     // it's defined right here
     public const String Differentiator = "primaryStars";
```

And here in the dto

```
public class MgalaxyGroupDto
{
    public Int32? Id { get; set; }
    public String TypeId{ get; set; }
    // it's here
    public String Differentiator { get; set; }
}
```

So why would it be saying `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?  I'm not quite sure what to do at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is one a constant and the other is an editable property?

Comment: Perhaps AutoMapper excludes `const` when mapping? Unless you get a better suggestion, perhaps change that to `public String Differentiator { get; } = "primaryStars";`

Comment: @gunr2171 Honestly I don't know. It's always been like that since I took over this Uni project.  We recently upgraded Automapper and ran into this issue.  I can try changing it match the dto to see if that fixes it.  Thanks!

Comment: You can just forego AutoMapper entirely if you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653618/how-can-i-map-constants-and-class-property-values-to-a-dictionaryint-object

Comment: @EricJ. if I do that, get: `Error -- An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property MgalaxyGroup.Differentiator `

Comment: @gunr2171 unfortunately we are pretty heavily invested in AutoMapper as it maps everything across the entire project.

Comment: That probably needs to be `opt => opt.MapFrom(m =>m.Differentiator)`. You're mapping to the type itself rather than an instance property of that type.