# Best way to convert a huge collection of key value pairs to C# object

Tags: c#, linq, collections, mapping

I have a web service that returns an object with multiple child objects. The parent object as well as the child object has a huge array of key value pairs (keyvaluepair[]). At this moment I am using linq to identify the keyvaluepair and then get the value.

For a smaller collection this process seems to be okay. But the object I am receiving from the service has more than 300 key value pairs and I am searching for an optimal way to map the key value pairs to my object.

Is there any good way to do this or any existing library that can help me do this?

Comment: 300 is hardly a huge collection...

Comment: For a one time process 300 might not be huge. In my case I have two web services of this kind which I have to use and map the object from key value pairs. There will be multiple calls to these web services continuously and I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should just build a dictionary:

```
var dictionary = pairs.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Then you can look up any entry by key very efficiently. Note that this *requires* that all the keys are distinct. If there can be multiple values for a key, use `ToLookup` instead.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to use ToLookup. In my case I do have duplicate keys so I guess ToLookup is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using jon's initial code and based off [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper) - If you already have the class defined you could cheat using a serializer

```
var dictionary = pairs.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var yourObject= serializer.Deserialize<yourObject>(serializer.Serialize(dictionary));
```