# Map Dictionary values to Entity object

Tags: c#

I have an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>` and I want to map it to an `IEnumerable<Entity>`. I was wondering what's the best way to do so?

E.g.

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> dictionary
```

where `dictionary.Select(x=>x.Values.ToList())` which will give me the values I want to store/map to my entity object but the keys in the dictionary will tell it which entity to map to.

So I want to do something like if key == entityPropertyName, then insert value and I want to do that for the entire collection.

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var csvToSave = serializer.Deserialize<entitiy>(serializer.Serialize(rows.ToDictionary(kvp=>kvp.Keys, kvp=>kvp.Values)));
```

But I get this issue:

```
Message :Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.
Source :System.Web.Extensions
```

Comment: take a look at automapper, it can map darn near anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper

Comment: @Sajeetharan see edit