# Convert list of dictionaries to list of classes

Tags: c#, wpf, list, dictionary, automapper

I have been playing around with Team Foundation Server 2018's API. I am able to connect to the API and retrieve a list of Work Items in the form of `List<IDictionary<string, object>>` but this format is not very usable. The data needs to be massaged a bit to be more usable and loop friendly.

For an example, I want to take this format of data and display it in a Data Grid. I created a simple WPF application, without any bells and whistles to work through this problem.

This example has a variable called `data` which has been created to resemble that of the data from my TFS system.

On the `MainWindow.xaml` all I created was a DataGrid named `DataGrid`. In the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I intend on mapping a `List<WorkItem>` to this DataGrid.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="AutoMapperExample.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="AutoMapper Example" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace AutoMapperExample.Views {
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;
    using AutoMapper;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            var data = new List<IDictionary<string, object>> {
                new Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {"System.Id", 1}, {"System.State", "Open"}, {"System.TeamProject", "Project1"}, {"System.Title", "First Work Item Title for Project 1"}
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {"System.Id", 2}, {"System.State", "Closed"}, {"System.TeamProject", "Project2"}, {"System.Title", "Work Item Title for Project 2"}
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object> {
                    {"System.Id", 3}, {"System.State", "Closed"}, {"System.TeamProject", "Project1"}, {"System.Title", "Second Work Item Title for Project 1"}
                }
            };

            DataGrid.ItemsSource = ParseData(data);
        }

        private IEnumerable<WorkItem> ParseData(List<IDictionary<string, object>> data) {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                //                cfg.CreateMap<List<IDictionary<string,object>>, List<WorkItem>>();
                //                cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, WorkItem>();
                //                cfg.RecognizePrefixes("System.");
                //                cfg.ReplaceMemberName("System.", string.Empty);
            });

            var workItems = Mapper.Map<List<WorkItem>>(data);

            return workItems;
        }
    }

    public class WorkItem {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Project { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please note the Keys of all the dictionaries are being prefixed with `System.` as well.

I decided to use AutoMapper to solve this problem and the resulting list contains the correct amount of items in it, but all the properties are default values or null. The example has commented code which shows what I have tried but they all have the same result.

Is AutoMapper the solution to this problem? If so what adjustments do I need to properly convert to my `List<WorkItem>`

Comment: A downvote with no comment helps no one. Please say what is wrong so I can correct it.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, but this seems to be a problem creating your `WorkItem` type from a `List<IDictionary<string,object>` using AutoMapper. A simpler question to answer would be how do I get `List<IDictionary<string,object>` into this class, and show some sample data - something anyone can run without getting TFS access working. Also, it would be easier if your code could just be copied and pasted and replaced with my credentials and TFS instace - an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I read through the thread, and the down vote might be because you could achieve similar results getting all of the "assigned to" work items through simple queries in TFS, but you are right that a comment is needed for that matter as well. I am up voting it now, so the question remains relevant.

Comment: Ok that is fair. I am going to modify this question then. I am going to keep a blurb about why the data I am receiving is in the form of `List<IDictionary<string,object>` but I will be making this about as what @DaveShaw suggested. Converting `List<IDictionary<string,object>` to a List of classes and display it into a DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cheat with intermediate serialization. Apply `[JsonProperty]` attributes on your model:

```cs
public class WorkItem
{
    [JsonProperty("System.Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.TeamProject")]
    public string Project { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

then implement custom type converter using `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer under the hood:

```cs
public class WorkItemTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<IDictionary<string, object>, WorkItem>
{
    public WorkItem Convert(IDictionary<string, object> source, WorkItem destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkItem>(json);
    }
}
```

and specify it's usage in AutoMapper configuration:

```cs
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, WorkItem>()
        .ConvertUsing<WorkItemTypeConverter>();
});
```

I based my answer on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310568/8065832) by Darin Dimitrov.

Comment: Interesting. I like this solution so much better than what I ended up with. I resorted to looping through the returned dictionary and stripping out "System." from the Key. Hated that solution so much.