# Unable to map Dictionary<string, string> to dto using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

My data model and dto are-

```
public sealed class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> References { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ReferenceDto
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UserReferenceDto
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReferenceDto> References { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

I am using AutoMapper nuget version 8.1.1. I have created profile maps as-

```
public sealed class UserProfile : Profile //AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ReferenceDto, KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                .ConstructUsing(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Type.Trim(), x.Id.Trim()));

            CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, string>, ReferenceDto>()
                .ConstructUsing(x => new ReferenceDto { Type = x.Key.Trim(), Id = x.Value.Trim() });

            CreateMap<User, UserReferenceDto>(); // Not working
        }
    }
```

I am able to achieve mapping

```
var references = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ReferenceDto>>(User.References)
```

But when I try to map User model to UserReferenceDto

```
var response = _mapper.Map<UserReferenceDto>(User);
```

I am getting UserId and Token mapped but getting empty collection for ReferenceDto. Tried several approaches but still getting empty collection.

Right now

```
var response = _mapper.Map<UserReferenceDto>(User);
response.References = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ReferenceDto>>(User.References);
```

working for me but I want to get this done with `_mapper.Map<UserReferenceDto>(User);` only.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper

Comment: I would probably suggest using a custom mapping profile, let me know if you need any help with it

Comment: @andyb952 I tried but didn't worked. Any help on this will be helpful to me.  @ Amine thnaks but the link you suggested is a diffent case, I already gone through it.

Comment: Call `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`.

Comment: I just tried this in an online compiler and it all works as expected? https://dotnetfiddle.net/xsek5a