# How to map a dictionary in a IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an issue using Automapper on C#.

I want to map a `Dictionary<string, string>` into an `IEnumerable<Object>` where my object is something like this :

```
public class Object
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want, for each key value in my dictionary, to add an object in my `IEnumerable` where

```
Code = dic.Key,
Name = dic.Value
```

Is there an easy way to do that with AutoMapper? Or do I have to write a method for this ?

Comment: Similar automapper question and its mapping solved between dictionary and custom object. Here is the answer [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310533/dictionary-string-string-map-to-an-object-using-automapper)

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not familiair with automapper, but it's easy enough using LINQ:

```
dictionary.Select(d => new Object { Code = d.Key, Name = d.Value })
```

This creates an IEnumerable with each item in your dictionary.

Comment: This is usefull for later, but I need to use automapper for this